# Symbols do not work in a swich/case within a reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, es6-symbol

This simple counter button does work as expected. Initially set to zero, its label is incremented each time I click on it:

```
function Counter() {
    const INCREMENT = 'INC';
    const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(reducer, { counter: 0 });

    function reducer(state, action) {
        switch (action.type) {
            case INCREMENT:
                return { counter: state.counter + 1 };
            default:
                throw new Error("Unknown action!");
        }
    }

    return <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: INCREMENT })}>{state.counter}</button>;
}
```

However, if I use Symbol for the INCREMENT constant, I get "Unknown action!" each time I click on it:

```
function Counter() {
    const INCREMENT = Symbol();
    const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(reducer, { counter: 0 });

    function reducer(state, action) {
        switch (action.type) {
            case INCREMENT:
                return { counter: state.counter + 1 };
            default:
                throw new Error("Unknown action!");
        }
    }

    return <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: INCREMENT })}>{state.counter}</button>;
}
```

Can you explain this behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're comparing two different Symbols. The `INCREMENT` used within your `reducer` is the `INCREMENT` symbol created for the current render (as you're redefining `reducer()` within your component, which is not typically done), whereas the `action.type` within your reducer is the symbol created for the previous render. That's because when you call `dispatch(action)`:

- Your component executes again, creating a fresh unique `INCREMENT` symbol. As you can't create the same Symbol twice with `Symbol()`, this is unique.
- Your `function reducer()` is redeclared, allowing it to access the new unique symbol just created.
- The line  `const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(reducer, { counter: 0 });` executes, triggering the `reducer` function to execute with `action` as an argument. Here action is your object from the previous render that has the old `INCREMENT` symbol.

As your new symbol `INCREMENT` is different from the old one `action.type`, they'll have different reference identities when compared in the `switch`.

Instead, you can create the `Symbol` outside of your component so that the symbol remains consistent across rerenders:

```js
const INCREMENT = Symbol();
function Counter() {
    const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(reducer, { counter: 0 });

    function reducer(state, action) {
        switch (action.type) {
            case INCREMENT:
                return { counter: state.counter + 1 };
            default:
                throw new Error("Unknown action!");
        }
    }

    return <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: INCREMENT })}>{state.counter}</button>;
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.body).render(<Counter />);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Alternatively, you can use `Symbol.for("INCREMENT")` which creates a "shared" symbol, but as [Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi) points out, this doesn't have many benefits over just using a string:

```js
function Counter() {
    const INCREMENT = Symbol.for("INCREMENT");
    const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(reducer, { counter: 0 });

    function reducer(state, action) {
        switch (action.type) {
            case INCREMENT:
                return { counter: state.counter + 1 };
            default:
                throw new Error("Unknown action!");
        }
    }

    return <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: INCREMENT })}>{state.counter}</button>;
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.body).render(<Counter />);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `Symbol.for` is no better than using a string in this case

Comment: @Bergi That is true - I suppose the better option is to go with the one symbol outside of the component then.

Comment: Thanks ! I know that React executes the component function at each render time but my brain resists... I move the symbol (and also the reducer function to make it more usual) outside of the component and all works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `const INCREMENT = Symbol();` creates a **new** symbol on every render of your `Counter` component. Define the reducer and the action type symbols outside of the component:

```
const INCREMENT = Symbol();
function reducer(state, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case INCREMENT:
            return { counter: state.counter + 1 };
        default:
            throw new Error("Unknown action!");
    }
}
const initial = { counter: 0 };

function Counter() {
    const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(reducer, initial);    
    return <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: INCREMENT })}>{state.counter}</button>;
}
```